# Bash: Extract URL from markdown format

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a set of markdown format posts for a jekyll site that each contain a markdown link. For example:

```
---
layout: post
title: "The Title"
date: 2022-07-31
categories:
- CategoryX
- CategoryY
author: AuthorName, SecondAuthor
tags: [tag1,tag2,tag3]
---

Some text that might contain (brackets] or other symbols.

[Visit Link](https://www.linkhere.net/somepage){:target="_blank" rel="noopener"}
```

I'd like to extract just the full URLs from each file in the _post directory and write them to a new file.

This is the code and commented attempts

```
#!/bin/bash

# configuration
jekyll_post_dir="<jekyll_dir>/_posts"


for file in $jekyll_post_dir/*
do
    #link=$(sed -n -e '/[Visit Link]/,/{:target/p' $file)

    #link=$(sed -n '/[Visit Link]/,/target/{ /html>/d; p }' $file)

    #link=$(awk '/[Visit Link]/,/target/' $file)

    #link=$(sed -n 's/[^{]*\({[^}]*}\).*/\1/g' $file)

    #link=$(sed 's/.*Link](\(.*\))/\1/' $file)

    #link=$(awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}' $file )

    #while IFS="](){" read a b; do echo "$b"; done < $file

    #link=$(sed -n '/\](/,/)\{:/p' $file)

    #echo $link >> linklist.txt

done
```

All my attempts have either selected unwanted text or failed completely. I am not familiar with regex or similar definitions so I would appreciate some guidance. I'm happy to use any bash-supported solution.

Thanks for reading/helping...

Comment: Great that you have posted your tried code as your efforts. Could you please also edit your question to update samples of output and input more clearly that will help us to test our codes(solutions) thank you

Comment: This might help: [How to use grep and cut in script to obtain website URLs from an HTML file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/181254/74329)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command below gets the expected URL

```
sed -nre '/:target=/ s/.*[]][(]([^)]+)[)][{]:target=.*/\1/p' test.txt
```

Result

```
https://www.linkhere.net/somepage
```

Alternative command

`sed -nre '/:target=/ s/.*\]\(([^)]+)\)\{:target=.*/\1/p' test.txt`